# Simple Clojure XML edit

Tags: xml, clojure, xml-generation

Let's say I have a vector of maps

```
[{:username "kbee" :firstname "Kay" :lastname "Bee"},
 {:username "jcee" :firstname "Jay" :lastname "Cee"}]
```

and i want to generate xml files for each map like the following

```
  <user>
   <username>kbee</username>
   <firstname>Kay</firstname>
   <lastname>Bee</lastname>
  </user>
```

how do i use just the clojure core library to achieve this. 
(I looked at enlive and fleet but they seemed a little complicated for me.)

ideally i'd like to do the following

```
(map #(spit (str (:username %) ".xml") (gen-xml sometemplate %) map-of-users))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try clojure.xml/emit-element ? :

```
(use 'clojure.xml)
(def v [{:username "kbee" :firstname "Kay" :lastname "Bee"},
        {:username "jcee" :firstname "Jay" :lastname "Cee"}])

(defn to-xml [m] (doseq [[k v] m] 
                  (emit-element {:tag k :content [v]}) ))
```

Try out at REPL:

```
user> (to-xml (first v))
<username>kbee
</username>
<firstname>Kay
</firstname>
<lastname>Bee
</lastname>
nil
```

All you need then is to wrap what's in the to-xml with a user tag.